# How to install multiple RPM packages using Shell script and by taking it from comma separated input file?

Tags: linux, shell-script, amazon-linux

I have to install multiple packages using shell script and rpm (package) name is in the input file.

I have done it in this below way.

My input file is path is = `/mstr/mstr_input_file.txt`

MY Script is:

```
cat ${filename} | while read line
do
    tag=$(echo "${line}"|awk -F'=' '{print $1}')
    value=$(echo "${line}"|awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
    if [[ "${tag}" = "packagelist" ]]; then
            for pkg in $(echo "${value}" | sed "s/,/ /g")
            do

                    sudo yum install -y "${pkg}" && sleep 5
            done
    fi
done
```

But instead using sleep command i need to keep condition when one package got installed it should start for another to install.

My input file contains:

```
packagelist=mailx,nc,expect,nfs-utils,telnet,glibc,libX11,libxcb,libXcomposite,libXcursor,libXdamage,libXext,libXfixes,libXi,libXrender,libXtst,glib2,nss,nss-util,nspr,cups-libs,dbus-libs,expat,libXScrnSaver,libXrandr,alsa-lib,cairo,at-spi2-atk,gtk3,gdk-pixbuf2,ibgcc,atk,at-spi2-atk,at-spi2-core,GConf2,libXScrnSaver,libxkbcommon,libwayland-client,libwayland-cursor,gtk3,gdk-pixbuf2
```

Comment: Is it Okay Now?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have a rpm based system in front of me to test that out but assuming your list is called rpmlist.txt and you want to install it with rpm and not yum.

First do:

```
for i in `cat rpmlist.txt | tr ',' '\n'`; do echo $i ; done
```

if the output shows a the packages now line by line it should work with:

```
for i in `cat rpmlist.txt | tr ',' '\n'`; do rpm -i $i ; done
```

**Note:** you could replace *rpm -i* with *yum -y* (the -y makes shure, you dont have to agree to install the packages it just install them without asking.)

Comment: Thanks @Dorian Gaensslen This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
yum install $(awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' filename)
```

`awk` command will give packages names separated by space as input to yum.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xargs` to feed comma separated values to a command:

```
xargs -d',' yum install < inputfile.csv
```

If you want to install the packages one by one, you could pass the `-n 1` flag to xargs:

```
xargs -n1 -d',' yum install < inputfile.csv
```

- `<` sends the input file to xargs
- `xargs -d','` takes ',' as delimiter to generate a list of arguments from the input file to pass them to yum.

You can find and split the lines starting with `packagelist` with `awk`:

```
</mstr/mstr_input_file.txt awk -F'=' '/packagelist=/{print $2}' | xargs -n1 -d',' yum install
```

Comment: In my Input file So many inputs are there not only rpm Packages